# How to use std::make_heap

Tags: c++, heap, std

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/push_heap/

It's so confusing. To use heaps in std, you first put the elements in a vector, then you call

```
std::make_heap(v.begin(), v.end());
```

What if I insert elements into the vector? Does the heap get messed up? For example v might initially have 10 elements, and I only make the heap from the 3rd element to the 7th element, and now I insert elements into the 5th place and 9th place, isn't the heap structure destroyed in the process?

And why do you have to `push_back(99)` first in the example, before calling `push_heap` again? Looks like not only confusing and also inefficient.

And what's the meaning of `sort_heap()`? Shouldn't the heap already be sorted, (that's what makes it a heap right?)

Comment: Voted to close as too broad. There is just too much to explain right now.

Comment: Could it be you've been searching for the meaning of _'heap memory'_ and stumbled over this?

Comment: so to put one element into the heap i have to make 2 function calls?

Comment: If you want to use the _heap data structure_ look into `std::queue`

Comment: A heap is not already sorted. It's just a heap with heap-properties.

Comment: I prefer this reference BTW: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap

Comment: no, my understanding is that heap is a binary tree structure which its elements are sorted such that leaf nodes are always smaller than its parent. But I don't understand why it has to be so confusing, not just some std::heap, and we simply insert items into the heap.

Comment: @seilgu, no, it's not like that. Does [this heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Max-Heap.svg) look ordered to you?

Comment: So make_heap builds a heap structure on the vector but doesn't change the order of elements in that vector, while sort_heap actually changes that order, is that right?

Comment: I vote to re-open: it is an useful question (4k view and +6 tell about it). Intelligent persons are able to sort/filter the answer so it fit for this format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all: `make_heap`, `push_heap`, `pop_heap` and `sort_heap` are mostly heap "primitives", in "normal work" you generally use `std::priority_queue`, which is way more straightforward to use (although it does have some other hideousnesses - namely, inability to directly access the underlying container and no equivalent of `sort_heap`).

---

`push_heap` and `pop_heap` are designed to work on a generic iterator-determined range, and, as usual with STL algorithms (see e.g. the various `std::remove_if` & co.), they cannot change the size of the underlying container (after all all you passed to them are a couple of iterators).

For this reason, `push_heap` and `pop_heap` will *not* actually add an element to the container, but will just patch up the order inside the range to include the new element/remove the top element and give back to the relevant range the "heap-property".

`push_heap` expects to receive a range such that [first, last-1) is already a heap (i.e. it has the heap property), and the element to be added to the heap is stored in the last position of the range (i.e. `last-1`). After `push_heap`, the whole range [first, last) is now a heap, with the new element being added.

This is the reason why in the example it *first* does the `push_back` (to put the new element ready to be manipulated by `push_heap`), and then calls `push_heap`.

On converse, `pop_heap` will start with the range [first, last) considered as a heap, then do its things and at the end you'll get [first, last-1) being a heap, and in the last position (i.e. `*(last-1)`) the highest element, extracted from the proper heap-range. That's why after the `pop_heap` the example does `pop_back`, reducing the vector size by 1, and thus discarding the extracted value, reducing the vector only to the range where it is an heap.

`sort_heap`, instead, is used because, although a heap uses a particular ordering to achieve its performance characteristics, it does not keep the range *sorted*; `sort_heap` destroys the heap (i.e. the range loses its heap properties) by sorting the elements (the sort exploits the heap properties, which potentially can give some performance gains over plain `std::sort`).

Answer (score 3):

> What if I insert elements into the vector? Does the heap get messed up?

Yes, it could. If you push a new element in the vector, you get a new vector which, maybe, is not an heap anymore.

> And why do you have to push_back(99) first in the example, before calling push_heap again? Looks like not only confusing and also inefficient.

No, it's not efficient. [`std::vector::push_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)'s complexity is pretty much constant. The real work is done by [`std::push_heap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap) which has a complexity of "at most 2×log(N)".

Notice that `std::make_heap` and `std::push_heap` are very different. The first does not make assumption on the state of the container, the second assumes the elements in `[begin, end-2)` are already a valid heap (making it more efficient, in the case of a `push_back`).

> And what's the meaning of sort_heap()? Shouldn't the heap already be sorted, (that's what makes it a heap right?)

A heap just have particular properties that make it easier to sort, but it's not already sorted. As an example, this is an *heap*:

[image]

And it's not sorted.

Comment: But here I'm asking from a coding-efficiency view. Why isn't there any way I can simply insert an element using one function call?

Comment: Ok, I see it's not sorted.

Answer (score 1):

I find this documentation less confusing: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm#Heap_operations

If you use `std::push_heap()` the heap-property is preserved.

If you insert one or more elements into the vector, then you must call `std::make_heap()` to restore the heap property.

> And what's the meaning of sort_heap()?
>   Shouldn't the heap already be sorted, (that's what makes it a heap right?)

Nope! You have to understand what an heap is. So `sort_heap()` turns a heap into a range of sorted elements.

Comment: "If you insert one or more elements into the vector, then you must call std::make_heap() to restore the heap property." -- No. You should call `std::push_heap`.

Comment: @Jeffery Are you sure? I think I remember from computer class that it might be faster to insert multiple elementes, then call `make_heap()` once at the end. It can be faster than keeping the heap-property after each insert, like `push_heap()` have to do.

Comment: If you insert a new element in the vector, it's much more efficient to call `std::push_heap`. I doubt inserting multiple elements and calling `std::make_heap` is much faster than pushing an element and calling `std::push_heap` repeatedly.

Comment: Aha! `push_heap()` can insert multiple elements. Then it does not matter and you should probably always use push_heap() as you say. My bad.